# How can I increase canvas size or plot area so that it does not crop labels in ggpubr::ggpie?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, ggpubr

I have the same problem as raised in [ggpubr #429](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/429): `ggpie` cuts off long names.

It seems the canvas (?plot area -  really not sure about vernacular) is too small

How could I fix it so that long names are not cropped?

Example from GH:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  group = c("Male", "Female", "Children but not teenager"),
  value = c(25, 25, 50))

ggpie(df, "value", label = "group")
```

[image]

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the source code of `ggpie` directly using `trace(ggpie, edit = TRUE)` and correcting their call to `coord_polar()` on line 26 by adding `clip = "off"`. This won't crop out text outside of the coordinate area.
Alternatively just copy the full source code, make this edit, and save to your own custom function to get this use across sessions.

```r
...) + coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, clip = "off") + .remove_axis()
```

Then we get:

```r
ggpie(df, "value", label = "group")
```

[image]

Alternatively, as @rawr mentions below, you can replicate the `coord_polar()` call to get the same results, just make sure you specify `theta = "y"`.

```r
ggpie(df, "value", label = "group") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", clip = "off")
```

Comment: why not just add it to the call? `ggpie(...) + coord_polar(...)`

Comment: Because I overthought it ha! Have added above.

Comment: Thanks so much, that was very elegant :-)